# How to disable recursive query of DNS java?

Tags: dnsjava

I'm doing query using dnsjava, and program did query 2 times, the first query is necessary and return desired result (this result only see if I capture UDP package, not in result of my program), and after that, it automatically do the second query and return error Host Not Found for my program
[tcpdump_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWPn.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        final Cache cache = new Cache(DClass.IN);           
        SimpleResolver resolver = new SimpleResolver("10.212.9.108");           
        Name name = new Name("8491698766.6.msisdn.sub.cs");
        Lookup.setDefaultResolver(resolver);
        Lookup.setDefaultCache(new Cache(), DClass.IN);

        Lookup l = new Lookup(name);
        l.setResolver(resolver);

        l.run();
        Record[] records = l.getAnswers();
        System.out.println("Error str: " + l.getErrorString());
    //  System.out.println("Record length: " + records.length);
    //  InetAddress[] array = new InetAddress[records.length];
        if(records != null) {
            for(int i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
                Record record = records[i];
                if(record instanceof ARecord) {
                    ARecord a = (ARecord)record;
                    System.out.println("ARecord: " + a.getAddress().getHostName() + ";" + a.getAddress().getHostAddress());
                }else {
                    CNAMERecord cname = (CNAMERecord)record;
                    System.out.println("CnameRecord: " + cname.toString());
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Record null");
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've just fixed this problem by change source code of Cache class in dnsjava.
In Cache class, just edit this function: public SetResponse
addMessage(Message in) , comment on this: if ((type == qtype || qtype == Type.ANY)) //&&
     // name.equals(curname))

Answer (score 3):

You just need to unset the `Recursion desired` Flag in the query header.

Assuming you have a DNS server with a zone `bob.` and the following entries:

```
peter.bob.              38400   IN      NS      ns2.bobsen-technology.org.
peter.bob.              38400   IN      NS      ns.klaus.de.
```

the code

```java
Resolver resolver = new SimpleResolver("localhost");

Record question = Record.newRecord(new Name("peter.bob."), Type.NS, DClass.IN);

Message query = Message.newQuery(question);

query.getHeader().unsetFlag(Flags.RD);

Message response = resolver.send(query);

for (RRset rRset : response.getSectionRRsets(Section.AUTHORITY)) {
    System.out.println(rRset);
}
```

produces:

```
{ peter.bob. 38400 IN NS [ns2.bobsen-technology.org.] [ns.klaus.de.] }
```